# Specify output type of arithmetic operation in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV, I can add two matrices of the same type using the `+` operator, like so:

`cv::Mat mat3 = mat1 + mat2;`

When I try to add two matrices of different types in this way, I get an error at runtime, which says that "When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified".

How should I go about specifying the output type for operations like this, when applying them to matrices of different types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"How should I go about specifying the output type"

unfortunately, the overloaded c++ operators won't let you specify that.

use code like:

```
cv::Mat mat3;
add(mat1, mat2, mat3, Mat(), CV_32F); // the additional Mat() is an empty Mask
```

as always, also see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga10ac1bfb180e2cfda1701d06c24fdbd6)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the size of Mat C first. Hopefully this can help